# How can I build fences?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try:

```
Wood plank | stick | wood plank
-------------------------------  
wood plank | stick | wood plank
```

in the crafting bench, it doesn't work.

Comment: What version of the game are you playing? The recipe was changed in 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

You can make fences by using any kind of wood to create fences.
To make a wood fence, you need 4 planks of any wood and 2 sticks.  The crafting recipe is plank, stick, plank on the second row of the crafting bench, and the same on the bottom row.
You could also create fences using nether brick to make nether brick fences.  To do this, the crafting recipe is:three nether brick on the second row of the crafting bench and the same on the bottom row.

The top row of the crafting table is supposed to be empty.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence
https://www.digminecraft.com/basic_recipes/make_spruce_fence.php

Answer (score 1):

An image:

[image]

Does that help? If you are looking for a different kind of fence, use different wood.

For a nether brick fence:

[image]

Comment: I think that you should put a picture on how nether brick fences are made.

Answer (score 0):

```
--x-- --x-- --x--
plank stick plank
plank stick plank
```

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fence

--x-- means an empty slot.  I don't think it works in the upper slots, gotta be the lower slots.

Answer (score -1):

as said by gatherer818, use this:

> --x-- --x-- --x--
>
> plank stick plank
>
> plank stick plank

**Make sure that you are using the same type of planks.**

minecraft has a fence for every type, so it is important to make sure everything is the same